# How to avoid complete refresh on button click in custom tab of Outllook Plugin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am new to Add in development . I have started working on **Outlook addin** development using `VSTO`.

I have **added a new tab** and placed a `buttton` in that tab . When ever i **click** on button , i am **sending an email** .

It is **working fine** . But , the problem is when ever i click on button , it is **flashing entire outlook screen that is complete reload.**

How to avoid this and do it gracefully , so that page does not get reloaded.

**Here , is my code for your reference :**

```
public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            SendAutoNotification();
        }

        public void SendAutoNotification()
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                Globals.AutoMailer.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "AutoGeneratedEmail";
            mailItem.To = "xxx.xxx@xxx.com";
            mailItem.Body = "This is just for test purpose. This is an auto generated email from outlook adddin";
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            ((Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what "flashing entire outlook screen that is complete reload" means?

Comment: It is reloading entire app screen when clicked on button .It is not same as other existing buttons in outlook . The other buttons are just processing the actions but not reloading the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the **Display** method of the MailItem class in the code:

```
public void SendAutoNotification()
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
            Globals.AutoMailer.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "AutoGeneratedEmail";
        mailItem.To = "xxx.xxx@xxx.com";
        mailItem.Body = "This is just for test purpose. This is an auto generated email from outlook adddin";
        mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
        ((Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Send();
    }
```

Comment: @Eugene..Spot on..Thats is why it is giving flickering effect . Accepting your answer..Thanks for your time